# For loop definition of a matrix?

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm making a replica of minesweeper in pygame, and I am trying to make a matrix to keep track of the bombs, but I do not understand a certain matrix definition that I saw online.

I've seen code online that does the following to define a matrix filled completely with zeroes:

```py
def create_table(n):
    return [[0] * n for i in range(n)]
```

Where n is the number of rows and columns in the matrix.

I don't understand how `[0] * n` produces, for example if `n=3`, `[0, 0, 0].`

Answer (score 1):

`[0] * 3` is basically just `[0] + [0] + [0]`. A similar example that might be clearer:

```
[1, 2, 3] + [4, 5] == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Depending on how you want your matrix to be laid out (either `matrix[row][column]` or `matrix[column][row]`), you have to replace the `n`s by `n_columns` and `n_rows`.